# SQL Server 2012 denies a granted permission, then can't resolve username

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2012, impersonation

I have a very strange behavior going on here.

We have a table set up, "Person", with a trigger that inserts the difference actions into "Person_History". From what I can tell, when I execute as myself, all goes well. But when I run this:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'DOMAIN\User';
INSERT INTO "Person_History" VALUES (...);
REVERT;
```

The first time, I get a permission error:

> Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The user does not have permission to perform this action.

The second time I run it (after tracing all the permissions and finding that this should be allowed), I get this:

> Msg 15406, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "DOMAIN\User" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

It should be noted that the first error is what the user sees, and reported, and I would expect the behavior not to change after the first run of the statement.

So what might I be missing here? I've never seen this behavior before.

**Update:** It turns out the insert was not the problem, it was acquiring the transaction ID from sys.dm_tran_current_transaction that was the problem. When the statement failed (for lack of VIEW SERVER STATE permission), revert was never run, and the user was not granted impersonate, thus why the message changed - we were still executing as the other user.

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously a difference in grants between you and that user. You need to double check the complete list (including roles).

Impersonating another user is also handled by grants. Run this to see what your grants are...

```
select * from sys.server_principals
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the insert was not the problem, it was acquiring the transaction ID from sys.dm_tran_current_transaction that was the problem (Trigger code not posted - apologies). When the statement failed (for lack of VIEW SERVER STATE permission), revert was never run, and the user was not granted impersonate, thus why the message changed - we were still executing as the other user.